# Azure DF: Get metadata of millions of files located in a VM and call a store procedure to update file details in a DB

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have created a Getmeta data activity in azure pipeline to fetch the file details located in a VM and I am iterating the output of Getmeta data activity using For each loop.
In the for each loop , I am calling a store procedure to update file details in the database.
If I have 2K files in the VM, the store procedure is called 2K times and which I feel not a good practice.

Is there any method to update all the file details in one shot ?

Comment: An alternative solution i found is, pass "Getmetadata" JSON output to the store procedure and inside the procedure parse JSON with OpenJSON library ans update table.
But when I pass JSON ouput to input parameter of Store procedure, the store procedure input parameter can define as varhcar(max) and it can accept only 8000 bytes, so for millions of files it will be more than 8000 butes

Comment: Here I am using SQL DB. 
Is there any option to use Azure function to convert metadata output JSON to a Array or List and pass to SP?

Or is there any method to write Getmetadata JSON output to a file and SP can cosume from there?

Comment: could you possible hold all the data in a staging table then call your SP? another procedure is to perhaps create a metadata master file and then have the SP call that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge, i think you could use GetMetadata Activity to get the output then pass it into [Azure Function Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity).

Inside azure function,you could loop the output and use sdk (such as [java sql lib](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html)) to update the tables as you want in the batch.